# Bit shifts in c++

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I don't understand why this gives me the same answer:

```
 long long a = 3265917058 >> 24;
 std::cout << a << std::endl; //194

 long long ip = 3265917058;
 long long b = ip >> 24;
 std::cout << b << std::endl; //194
```

but this don't:

```
 long long a = (3265917058 << 16) >> 24;
 std::cout << a << std::endl; //240

 long long ip = 3265917058;
 long long b = (ip << 16) >> 24;
 std::cout << b << std::endl; //12757488 - **i want this to be 240 too!**
```

Update: I want 32bit shift , but how can i 32bit shift a number that is too large for an int variable?
Update2: My answer is to make unsigned int ip. Then everything will be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your literal constant `3265917058` is an `int`. Add a `LL` suffix to get the expected behavio(u)r:

```
long long a = (3265917058LL << 16) >> 24;
```

Comment: but how do i get answer 240 if i use variable? I cant store 3265917058 in a int.

Comment: @Stals: your constant still fits in 32 bits - it just gets treated modulo 2^32 - the bit representation is the same. A decent compiler should warn you about this - do you have warnings enabled ?

Comment: what sould i do to get 240 here?
 std::cout<<b<<std::endl;//12757488

Comment: @Stals: change the declaration of `ip` from `long long` to `unsigned int`: `unsigned int ip = 3265917058; long long b = (ip << 16) >> 24; std::cout << b << std::endl;`

Answer (score 2):

`3265917058<<16` both sides are `int`, so the operation will be done in `int` (32-bits).

You need `3265917058LL<<16` then the left-side will be a `long long` and the operation will be done with that width i.e. 64-bits.

Answer (score 1):

To get what you ask for:

```
long long ip=3265917058;
long long b= (static_cast<unsigned int>(ip)<<16)>> 24;
std::cout<<b<<std::endl; // 240
```

Note that the result you will get (240) is not portable. Mathematically, the result should be 12757488. The value 240 is due to truncation, and this is not guaranteed to happen. For instance, it doesn't happen on systems where `int` is 64 bits.